# how to wait for the API response before displaying the switch component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

My problem is that I want to display a Switch with `defaultvalue = {true}` if `this.state.params4GInfo.status4G = 1`, otherwise a Switch with `defaultvalue = {false}`. But the problem here that `this.state.params4GInfo.status4G` equals `undefined` at the beginning, then it takes as value 1 after the rendering of the component.
so how can I wait for `this.state.params4GInfo.status4G` to take 1?

Here's my component:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getParameteres4GAction()
    }


    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.params4GInfo !== prevState.params4GInfo && nextProps.params4GInfo) {
            return {params4GInfo: nextProps.params4GInfo,status:nextProps.params4GInfo.status4G};
        } 
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>

            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitModeConnection}>
                    {console.log("statussss",this.state.status)}
                    <div className="sn-4GSetup-switchPos">
                        {console.log("statusssss",this.state.status)}
                        {this.state.params4GInfo.status4G !== undefined && 
                         this.state.params4GInfo.status4G == 1 ?
                            <div>
                            <Switch
                             onChange={this.changeHandlerActivied}
                             defaultChecked={true}
                      />
                            </div>:<div>
                                {console.log("i'm hereeeee")}
                            <Switch
                             onChange={this.changeHandlerActivied}
                             defaultChecked={false}
                      />
                            </div>}
                    </div>
                </Form>

         );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

considering **getParameteres4GAction()** is an API event, you will have to make your componentDidMount cycle wait for the API call to complete. Try this

```
async componentDidMount(){
    await this.props.getParameteres4GAction()
}
```

share your full code.. i could show you, how it works..

Comment: I tried with this async / await method but unfortunately I have the same problem

Comment: again.. i would say.. could you share you full code.. probably at `codesandbox.com`

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your conditions to

```
this.state.params4GInfo.status4G == undefined || this.state.params4GInfo.status4G == 1
```